# App store Ad Hoc provisioning profile no beta entitlement

Tags: app-store, provisioning-profile, testflight

I was told for push notifications to work properly in test flight, that I need to use an ad hoc provisioning profile. But when I create an ad hoc provisioning profile, it doesn't contain the beta entitlement, and I can't test in test flight.

How do I get an ad hoc provisioning profile with a beta entitlement?

Comment: Hey! Did you manage to solve the problem after all?

Answer (score 0):

This has changed when Apple took over test-flight. Now to test with test flight you need an App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile for external testing. To test internally a normal Development Profile should be enough, however it's recommended to also use a Distribution Profile here.

Hope that helps,
Julian